# How do I get specific line text in a textview and use webview to load the text(url)

Tags: java, android, textview, android-webview

Recently I want to get specific line text in a textview and I want to use a webview to load the text，I ve found some code references which I think is useful but not work for me well.

Textview:

```
A
Http://ABC.com.jp
C
```

I want to load line 2 URL.

Comment: I did some tests before I try in webview.I tried textView.getLayout().getLineStart(int line) and getLineEnd() then I got crashed when I entered the app.I don't know why but the code no error(s) is shown.

Comment: In addition I don't know how to log the error so I can't catch the error codes

Comment: I assume the textView you mean is `android.widget.TextView`, and you are trying to get the contents of the second line? And it depends on what development environment you are using, eclipse shows its errors in logcat: http://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/postimages/9274/nyanlogcat.jpg

Comment: Yes I am trying get the contents of the second line but is there any way to get the contents of the second line successfully?Thanks a lot!Give me some tips if you don't want paste the whole code～

Comment: You can get all the contents with `textview.getText()` (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText%28%29). You just have to split it in lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have solved the problem right now.

Comment: By the way sorry I forgot to tell you that I use eclipse to develop my project

Comment: Then you found a solution, then please don't write "solved" into the title. Post your solution instead, so future readers   can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my low responsibility, now I still updating and modifying my source code,I am new in java and this is not my main profit,besides I will keep learning.

```
    Target =(TextView)findViewbyid(R.id.abc);
    myTextView = (TextView)findViewbyid(R.id.id1);
    int startL= myTextView.getLayout().getLineStart(2);
    //^start line
    int endL = myTextView.getLayout().getLineEnd(3);
    //^end line
    String getResults = myTextView.getText().substring(startL, endL);
    Target.setText(getResults);
    //benefits of using get line end & start is that it can select multiple line content from a large content,also it can be used in selecting single line or specific line.
```